# HQL: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, hql

I'm new to HQL and I need help on this error.

QUERY:

```
 String hqlsearchSelect =
                "select new com.eteligent.core.loans.paging.LoansAppCustomerPageItem("
                    + "main.loanno, (SELECT acct.id.clientid FROM LMSAccountInfo acct WHERE acct.loanno = main.loanno), (SELECT acct.name FROM LMSAccountInfo acct WHERE acct.loanno = main.loanno), main.acctsts, "
                    + "main.loanbal, (SELECT acct.matdt FROM LMSAccountInfo acct WHERE acct.loanno = main.loanno) )";
```

I think the query can't identify which record is it going to return.

CONSTRUCTOR(LoansAppCustomerPageItem):

```
public LoansAppCustomerPageItem( final String acctNo, final String cifNo, final String customerName, final Integer acctStat, final BigDecimal acctBal, final Date acctDueDate )
{
    super();
    this.acctNo = acctNo;
    this.cifNo = cifNo;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.acctStat = acctStat;
    this.acctBal = acctBal;
    this.acctDueDate = acctDueDate;
}
```

Comment: Are the relationships mapped properly? Are the relationships all one-to-one? What does the constructor look like on the LoansAppCustomerPageItem class?

Comment: There is no relationship between the two tables that is why I resorted to using Subquery. I've edited the above post to include the constructor.

Comment: HQL is not a good tool for this job. It is meant to be used with mapped entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna just one row from subquery use `LIMIT 1` at the end of subquery.

Comment: I've tried using LIMIT but it gives me error. I think it was never implemented in HQL. Some people say that I should use query.setMaxResults(), but it limits all of my result.